# Add class to previous element if current element has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-tables

I want to target a table which is outside of the element I'd like to use as a 'trigger' and then give it an additional class.

```
<div>
 <table class="table"></table>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="trigger">
 <!---content open--->
</div>
```

The class "trigger" only appears when that div is open, so when it's open and the class is added, I want to target the table directly above it, and ONLY that table. The problem is that the table class "table" appears more than once on the page and there is always a further div between the two elements. How would I select only that one table directly before?

Comment: You could do `$('.trigger').prevUntil('.table'').prev()` but first you'd have to figure out when the element has the `.trigger` class, and what event to hook into ?

Comment: Do you use any jQuery/javascript to add 'trigger' to the div?

Comment: Hi, if you don`t want to use jQuery you can add a parent div and match css styles with parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your HTML structure, where the table you're trying to match is a child of a sibling node to trigger:

Get all the preceding siblings of trigger with `prevAll()`, search within them for a `.table` with `find()`, and keep the last one in the resulting match.

```js
var preceding = $('.trigger').prevAll().find('.table').last();
$(preceding).addClass('match'); // for demo, so you can see what matched
```

```css
.match {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table class="table"><tr><td>Don't want this table</td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>
  <table class="table"><tr><td>Do want this table</td></tr></table>
</div>
<div>This sibling doesn't have a table</div>
<div class="trigger">This is the trigger</div>
<div class="table">Don't want this div</div>
<div>
  <table class="table"><tr><td>or this table</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

This is pretty fragile.  If possible, consider using specific classnames or IDs instead of depending on document order.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible for that to be toggled on or off for the 'trigger' div being open or closed?

Comment: sure, though it'd probably be better to handle that as part of whatever event opens or closes the trigger div, rather than watching the trigger div's state.

Comment: It's not quite working as I want as the open div 'trigger' contains checkboxes which, when checked, refreshes the page automatically and seems to reset the area. As a novice here I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to refresh the page (which does reset everything, yeah) if you're just toggling a div's visibility.   Hard to give advice on how to fix that part without seeing your existing code, though; if you can boil down however you're firing events from those checkboxes that would help. (Probably as a new question rather than an update to this one, since it's pretty far distinct from what you asked here.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add a class to your table, right? If this is the case, you could add an id to the only table you want to modify and then use `addClass`.

```
<script>
    //perform condition checking
    $("#myTableID").addClass("class_to_add");
</script>
...
<div>
   <table id="myTableID"></table>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="trigger">
  <!---content open--->
</div>
```